# How long will the Spring 2010 MacBook Pros be available?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm thinking about picking up a refurb 13" 2010 MBP next month. But I just started wondering, how long will they be available?

Answer (score 2):

They will be available until they run out.

As you are looking at a refurbished product, availability is limited and highly variable. Apple tends to have a continuous supply of refurbished products, however they may not have the specific model you are looking for next month.